# options binding and event handling in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I implemented a page in my application that user can select an author from a drop down menu and see all books and their details for that specific author. The data binding in the jsp page is as follow:

```
<select id="author-dropdown"
        data-bind="options: authors,
                   value: selectedAuthor,
                   optionsText: currentAuthorName,
                   event: { change: getBooksDetails }">
```

It is working fine but there is a big problem with the options binding. When user change something in the the book table (below the drop down) but not save them and then try to change the author from the drop down, then a modal pops up that asks *"Do you want to save the changes?"*

User has three options:

- confirm to save
- confirm to not save
- close the modal.

If user *close the modal* nothing would happen and already the value of the author has been change to the new one and if user clicks save at the bottom of the table, then the book details would get saved to the wrong author!

I am really confuse about the behavior of knockout.js for options binding, and my question is how can I have control on the options binding in this scenario? How can I get the previous value of `selectedAuthor` if the user close the modal?

Comment: There is no notion of unsaved changes or old value unless you write one. See http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable that stores either a default value or the last saved value of your dropdown so, you can keep track of old value and then set your dropdown value back to the old one if user cancels the modal. Below I just show you the logic but you might need to change that based on your model and data.https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/51/

```
 function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this ;
    self.selectedAuthor = ko.observable("SecondAuthor");
    self.authors = ko.observableArray([{"currentAuthorName":"FirstAuthor",value:"FirstAuthor"},{"currentAuthorName":"SecondtAuthor",value:"SecondAuthor"},        {"currentAuthorName":"ThirdAuthor",value:"ThirdAuthor"}]);

        self.oldSelectedAuthor = ko.observable(self.selectedAuthor());

    self.Save = function(){
      self.oldSelectedAuthor(self.selectedAuthor());
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
    self.Cancel = function (){
        self.selectedAuthor(self.oldSelectedAuthor())
    }
    self.showModal = function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
  }


ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade lcmsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div><strong>CurrentSelectedDropDown:</strong> </div>
      <div data-bind="text:selectedAuthor">SelectedDropDown: </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click:Cancel">CANCEL</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:Save">SAVE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: authors ,value:selectedAuthor">
<option data-bind="value: value,text:currentAuthorName"></option>
<input type="button" value ="Show Modal" data-bind="click:showModal">
```